# Outlook Add-in - saveAsync fails in Online Meeting mobile add-in

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to create an online meeting mobile add-in for Outlook, as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/online-meeting). The add-in itself works fine, but I would like to try and save the appointment using the [saveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentcompose?view=outlook-js-preview#saveAsync_callback_) javascript call.

Calling this throws an exception - "Failed to save - Permission Denied: you don't have sufficient permissions for this action". I'm not convinced this is genuinely only a permissions issue, as I have ReadWriteMailbox permissions in the manifest, and the SaveAsync works fine on Desktop and Web.

Is there anything else I need to do to get this working, or is saving unsupported for online meeting add-ins?

Comment: Is it failing in Android or iOS?

Comment: iOS. I get a different result on android - instead of throwing, the saveAsync call succeeds, but the appointment is not saved to the server, and the return value is "undefined"

Comment: saveAsync API is not supported on Mobile. Thanks for reporting this, we will update documentation.

Comment: Please find the list of API's documented for Online Meeting in mobile https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/online-meeting#available-apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per MSFTs comment on the question, the saveAsync call is not supported on mobile.